# Spark Parallel Operations

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Here is my driver program (in pseudo code):

```
// read all the files
df1 = spark.read(f1)
df2 = spark.read(f2)
df3 = spark.read(f3)
```

...

```
df10 = spark.read(f10)

// crossjoin each pair and report the count<br>
cdf1 = df1.crossjoin(df2)
print cdf1.count
...
cdf5 = df9.crossjoin(df10)
print cdf5.count
```

When I do a spark-submit and go to the tracker UI, I see each job being executed in sequence. I would have expected each load to happen in parallel, each crossjoin to happen in parallel.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run different actions in parallel. You should use the Future Tasks for parallel execution of two different actions. Here is en example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)

import java.util.concurrent.Callable
val future1 = executorService.submit(new Callable[Long]() {
  @throws[Exception]
  override def call: Long = {
    df1.crossJoin(df2)
    df1.count
  }
})

val future2 = executorService.submit(new Callable[Long]() {
  @throws[Exception]
  override def call: Long = {
    df1.crossJoin(df3)
    df1.count
  }
})
println(future1.get())
println(future2.get())
```